# Counting occurrences in an expression

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm pretty new to Haskell and I have an assessment which involves a manipulator and evaluator of boolean expressions.

Thee expression type is:

```
type Variable = String
data Expr = T | Var Variable | And Expr Expr | Not Expr
```

I've worked through a lot of the questions but i am stuck on how to approach the following function. I need to count the occurences of all the variables in an expression

```
addCounter :: Expr -> Expr
addCounter = undefined

prop_addCounter1 = addCounter (And (Var "y") (And (Var "x") (Var "y"))) == 
                   And (Var "y1") (And (Var "x2") (Var "y1"))
prop_addCounter2 = addCounter (Not (And (Var "y") T)) == 
                   Not (And (Var "y1") T)
```

I'm not looking for an answer on exactly how to do this as it is an assessment question but I would like some tips on how I would go about approaching this?

In my head I imagine incrementing a counter so that I can get the `y1`, `x2` part but this isn't really something that is possible in Haskell (or not advised to do anyway!) Would I go about this through recursion and if so how do I know what number to add to the variable?

Comment: in `prop_addCounter1`, why does `x` get updated to `x2`?  `x` only occurs once in the input expression.

Comment: n/m I think I understand the purpose of the counter now

Comment: By the way, I think your teacher did a great job in giving you this task. Often enough, they just teach you the nice, simple, pure stuff, giving the impression that managing state in Haskell is overly complex or even impossible, while there are actually very elegant solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As you say you cannot keep a shared counter which would be very natural in this case. What you can do instead is to pass the current counter value down the tree as you recursively visit all Expr's, and receive back the incremented counter value from the function being called. It *must* be a two-way communication. You pass down the current value and receive back the updated Expr and the new counter value.

If you want each unique variable name to have the same counter value you need to keep a mapping of variable names to assigned counter values. You need to pass that one around just like the current counter value.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually you *can* keep a shared counter, using the state monad. I think this is a good idea here, otherwise the code will get messy really soon

Comment: @NiklasB. I'm not experienced with Haskell so I'd actually like to hear more about it (maybe an answer?). Anyway, it must be a "fake" way to keep state that just looks like it is mutating stuff. Does such a think help?

Comment: Passing a value down the function tree, receiving back a response and feeding that response into the next recursive call is also a "fake" way to maintain state, albeit a very cumbersome one :) The general structure of a function that mutates some state is `s -> (a, s)` and the state monad abstracts this pattern away very nicely. After defining a context, you can then write functions like `lookupOrCreateIndex :: String -> NameM Int` and let it do all the state transformations

Comment: Thanks but the state monad documentation went over my head! As this is an assignment, i feel that using it would over complicate things unnecessarily. I understand the first answer about passing the current counter down the recursion tree but don't know how that would actually work in practice.

Currently i have written the following function which substitutes it for "n". All i need is replace n with an incrementing number

    build :: Expr -> [(String, Expr)]
    build T = []
    build (Var x) = [(x, (Var (x++"n")))]
    build (And x y) = (build x) ++(build y)
    build (Not x) = build x

Comment: @jimbob868: The problem is that the value `n` you need is dependent on the number and the names of variables you have assigned so far. Also, it's not sufficient to have an incrementing number, because you need to reuse the index if you encounter a name for the second time. As usr described, you can pass a counter value and a name assignment map down the recursive calls. You will need to pay special attention for the case `And x y`, where you need to recurse twice. As I said, this will get messy without the state monad, but it's managable if you properly refactor the common glue code out.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i started to implement a solution passing through the recursive calls but it got very long winded quickly as @NiklasB. said it would but during the process discovered a way to actually use the library function `enumFromTo` to generate the numbers and pattern matching to get variables on their own and then merge the lists together to get desired results.

Comment: @jimbob868: Sounds interesting, care to post your result as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

### Atomize your stateful updates

So, this is definitely a great time to use a `State` monad. In particular, the atomic transform you're looking for is a way to take `String -> String` enumerating strings by a unique id for each string. Let's call it `enumerate`

```
import Control.Monad.State

-- | This is the only function which is going to touch our 'Variable's
enumerate :: Variable -> State OurState Variable
```

To do this, we'll need to track state that maps `String`s to counts (`Int`s)

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
type OurState = Map String Int

runOurState :: State OurState a -> a
runOurState = flip evalState M.empty

runOurState $ mapM enumerate ["x", "y", "z", "x" ,"x", "x", "y"]
-- ["x1", "y1", "z1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "y2"]
```

so we can implement enumerate pretty directly as a stateful action.

```
enumerate :: Variable -> State OurState Variable
enumerate var = do m <- get
                 let n = 1 + M.findWithDefault 0 var m
                 put $ M.insert var n m
                 return $ var ++ show n
```

Cool!

---

### Folding generically over an expression tree

Now we really ought to write an elaborate folding apparatus which maps `Expr -> State OurState Expr` by applying enumerate on each `Var`-type leaf.

```
enumerateExpr :: Expr -> State OurState Expr
enumerateExpr T = return T
enumerateExpr (Var s) = fmap Var (enumerate s)
enumerateExpr (And e1 e2) = do em1 <- addCounter e1
                            em2 <- addCounter e2
                            return (Add em1 em2)
enumerateExpr (Not expr) = fmap Not (addCounter expr)
```

But this is pretty tedious, so we'll use the `Uniplate` library to keep dry.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Data
import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data

data Expr = T | Var Variable | And Expr Expr | Not Expr 
  deriving (Show,Eq,Ord,Data)

onVarStringM :: (Variable -> State OurState Variable) -> Expr -> State OurState Expr
onVarStringM action = transformM go
  where go :: Expr -> State OurState Expr
        go (Var s) = fmap Var (action s)
        go x       = return x
```

The `transformM` operator does just what we want—apply a monadic transformation over all the pieces of a generic tree (our `Expr`).

So now, we just unpack the `State`ful action to make `addCounter`

```
addCounter :: Expr -> Expr
addCounter = runOurState . onVarStringM enumerate
```

---

### Oh, wait!

Just noticed, this doesn't actually have the right behavior—it doesn't enumerate your variables quite right (`prop_addCounter1` fails but `prop_addCounter2` passes). Unfortunately, I'm not really sure how it ought to be done... but given this separation of concerns laid out here it'd be very easy to just write the appropriate `enumerate` `State`ful action and apply it to the same generic `Expr`-transforming machinery.

Comment: I think `let n = M.findWithDefault (1 + M.size m) var m` in `enumerate` would do the trick: if you've already assigned a number to a variable, use that; otherwise, get a fresh number. I haven't tested this, though, and it will cause spurious updates to `m` (but that might be fixable using `M.insertWith const` or something similar).

Comment: I don't think the `enumerateExpr` function looks that bad, if you use a `case` and applicative style I don't think you need the full magic of `Data` for that :)

Comment: That's why I included both, but since it *is* a generic transformation I felt it better to use some pretty well-established SYB code to focus on the important part. I didn't include `Applicative` since I'm already introducing Monads and `Uniplate`